# We can't save the invoice right now 1054 Unknown column Magento 2.1.6

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Please have anyone of you any idea about this issue?

I tried to create invoice from the backend and i see this error

We can't save the invoice right now

and exception.log contains

```
Next Zend_Db_Statement_Exception: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sales_order_address.telephone' in 'field list', query was: INSERT INTO `sales_invoice_grid` (`telephone`) SELECT 
                     sales_order_address.telephone
                 AS `telephone` FROM `sales_invoice`
 LEFT JOIN `sales_order` ON sales_invoice.order_id = sales_order.entity_id
 LEFT JOIN `sales_order_address` AS `sales_shipping_address` ON sales_invoice.shipping_address_id = sales_shipping_address.entity_id
 LEFT JOIN `sales_order_address` AS `sales_billing_address` ON sales_invoice.billing_address_id = sales_billing_address.entity_id
 LEFT JOIN `sales_order_payment` ON sales_invoice.order_id = sales_order_payment.parent_id WHERE (sales_invoice.entity_id = '2611') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `telephone` = VALUES(`telephone`) in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235
Stack trace:

ALTER TABLE `sales_invoice_grid`
    ADD COLUMN `base_grand_total` DECIMAL(12,4) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Grand Total' AFTER `grand_total`;

#0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(95): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement.php(303): Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `sa...', Array)
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(465): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `sa...', Array)
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(520): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_query('INSERT INTO `sa...', Array)
#6 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/ResourceModel/Grid.php(87): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `sa...')
#7 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-sales/Observer/GridSyncInsertObserver.php(64): Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Grid->refresh('2611')
#8 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(73): Magento\Sales\Observer\GridSyncInsertObserver->execute(Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#9 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(61): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod(Object(Magento\Sales\Observer\GridSyncInsertObserver), Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#10 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php(66): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch(Array, Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#11 /var/www/html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch('sales_order_inv...', Array)
#12 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Model/ResourceModel/Db/VersionControl/RelationComposite.php(53): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy->dispatch('sales_order_inv...', Array)
#13 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Model/ResourceModel/Db/VersionControl/AbstractDb.php(57): Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\VersionControl\RelationComposite->processRelations(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice))
#14 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Model/ResourceModel/Db/AbstractDb.php(408): Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\VersionControl\AbstractDb->processAfterSaves(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice))
#15 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php(631): Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb->save(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice))
#16 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Transaction.php(129): Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->save()
#17 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Invoice/Save.php(192): Magento\Framework\DB\Transaction->save()
#18 /var/www/html/var/generation/Magento/Sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Invoice/Save/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice\Save->execute()
#19 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(102): Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice\Save\Interceptor->execute()
#20 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(226): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#21 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice\Save\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#23 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Sales\\C...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice\Save\Interceptor), Array, 'adminAuthentica...')
#24 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#25 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice\Save\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#26 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Sales\\C...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice\Save\Interceptor), Array, 'adminMassaction...')
#27 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/MassactionKey.php(33): Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice\Save\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#28 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\MassactionKey->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice\Save\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#29 /var/www/html/var/generation/Magento/Sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Invoice/Save/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice\Save\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#30 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice\Save\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#31 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#32 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#33 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#34 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#35 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#36 /var/www/html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#37 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#38 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#39 /var/www/html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#40 {main} [] []
```

Comment: Your `sales_order_address` table is missing `telephone` field, which exists in default installation.

Comment: Hey bro, the sales_order_address table is already exist also telephone column.